# Как удалить этот PPA репозиторий?

Tags: debian, gpg

В консоль выдает:

> Ошибка GPG: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886

Пробовал делать:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:launchpad.net
```

но ничего не выходит. как удалить его? я не могу до конца сделать `apt-get update`.

Вот все, что выводится в консоль:

> Получено:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15,5 kB]
>   Игн http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
>   Игн http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources/DiffIndex
>   Игн http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
>   Игн http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
>   В кэше http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
>   В кэше http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources
>   В кэше http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
>   В кэше http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
>   Игн http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-ru_RU
>   Игн http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-ru
>   Получено 627 kБ за 9с (68,8 kБ/c)
>   Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
>   W: Ошибка GPG: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886

ОС Debian 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

к сожалению, вы не привели всей информации, которую вам сообщила программа *apt-get*. там должно было быть указано и имя репозитория, с которым возникли проблемы.

судя по встречающимся в интернете упоминаниям строки *C2518248EEA14886*, этим ключом подписаны пакеты то ли в репозитории *webupd8*, то ли в репозитории *vlc*.

для «отключения» репозитория можно, например, закомментировать строки, в которых встречаются эти слова (*webupd8* или *vlc*). нужные файлы можно найти, например, так:

```
$ grep -rlE '(webupd8|vlc)' /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

«закомментировать» — это вставить символ `#` в начало строки.

---

**дополнение**

если искомые слова не нашлись, стоит поискать слова *ppa* или *trusty*:

```
$ grep -rlE '(ppa|trusty)' /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

ввиду того, что в дистрибутиве *debian* не используется по умолчанию «левых» репозиториев (с того же, например, сайта *ppa.launchpad.net*), а *trusty* — кодовое имя одного из выпусков **другого** дистрибутива — *ubuntu*, таких строк у вас вряд ли много. попробуйте закомментировать их все. или выборочно, пока ошибка не исчезнет.

Comment: Или можно добавить ключ достаточно универсальной командой: `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$(apt-get update 2>&1 | grep -o "[0-9A-F]\{16\}" | xargs)"`

Comment: @donRumata, ну, я отвечал непосредственно на заданный вопрос. напишите и свой вариант ответа (не забыв согласовать кавычки).

Comment: Обновил пост, надеюсь теперь достаточно инфы.

Comment: @eSkry, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ответ пилить в лом, а учитывая, что у человека дебиан, то я вообще бы посоветовал сделать `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*ppa*`.